# What is a real world use for ConcurrentBag<T>?

Tags: .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

A ConcurrentBag will allow multiple threads to add and remove items from the bag. It is possible that a thread will add an item to the bag and then end up taking that same item right back out. It says that the ConcurrentBag is unordered, but how unordered is it? On a single thread, the bag acts like a Stack. Does unordered mean "not like a linked list"?

What is a real world use for ConcurrentBag?

Comment: What do you mean "how unordered is it"? There's either a defined order or there isn't. That's like saying "How dead is Elvis?"

Comment: The ordering of the stored elements is none of the client's business. So from an API point of view, "unordered" always refers to the order of enumeration (from the `GetEnumerator` method).

Comment: "not ordered" means that there are no guarantees about the order. The current implementation's behavior appears to be that it acts like a stack when the same thread is adding and removing, and like a queue when one thread takes from another's collection. But I wouldn't count on that behavior. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=842 for a bit more info. `ConcurrentBag` can give better performance than `ConcurrentQueue` if the order isn't important, and if threads can be both producer and consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bags are really useful for tracking instance counts. For example, if you want to keep a record of which hosts you're servicing web requests for, you can add their IP to the bag when you start servicing the request, and remove it when done.

Using a bag will allow you to tell at a glance which IPs you're currently servicing. It will also let you quickly query whether you're servicing a given IP address.

If you use a set for this rather than a bag, then having multiple concurrent requests from the same IP address will mess up your record-keeping.

Comment: You say add their IP to the bag and then remove it when done. How do you remove a specific item from a bag?

Comment: @Dustin: Good question. I was thinking of [`ConcurrentHashMultiset`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html) (the Java equivalent of `ConcurrentBag`) when I was writing my answer, which _does_ have a `remove` method. I have no idea what the .NET `ConcurrentBag` class is good for, then. :-P

Comment: Thats ok, based on your answer I was able to come up with a real world scenario applicable to my self.

Comment: This is a case for a thread-safe hashset - which can be created using an underlying `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score 24):

Because there is no ordering the ConcurrentBag has a performance advantage over ConcurrentStack/Queue. It is implemented by Microsoft as local thread storage. So every thread that adds items does this in it's own space. When retrieving items they come from the local storage. Only when that is empty the thread steals item from another threads storage. So instead of a simple list a ConcurrentBag is a distributed list of items. And is almost lockfree and should scale better with high concurrency.

Unfortunately in .NET 4.0 there was a performance issue (fixed in 4.5) see 
http://ayende.com/blog/156097/the-high-cost-of-concurrentbag-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 1):

Anything where you just need to keep track of what's there and don't need random access or guaranteed order.  If you have a thread that adds items to process, and a thread that removes items in order to process them, a concurrent bag would work well if you don't care that they're processed in FIFO order.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Chris Jester-Young I came up with a good, real world, scenario that actually applies to a project i'm working on.

**Find - Process - Store**

**Find** - threads 1 & 2 are set to find or scrape data (file system, web, etc). These results are stored in ConcurrentBag1.

**Process** - threads 3 & 4 are set to take out of ConcurrentBag1, clean/transform/process the data and then store the results in ConcurrentBag2.

**Store** - threads 5 is set to gather results from ConcurrentBag2 and store the results in SQL.

Comment: From the description, this sounds like it would be better implemented using layered queues (possibly `ConcurrentQueue` or `BlockingCollection` instances) rather than the `ConcurrentBag` class. There appears to be a fair amount of overlap between the class usage though so I may be mistaken.